# IAP Billing Period and Price Change

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription, google-play-console, android-billing

There are multiple auto-renewable subscription plans that a user can select from and the subscriptions have been configured in "Google Play Console" with monthly billing period. During the change of price, I want the new price to be effective immediately for new users and for the old users I want them to be charged with old price for a year. However, after a year, the old users should automatically be charged with the new price. I want the billing period to be monthly at any cost, so is there any work around for this requirement?

Comment: You can't change the price of an existing subscription. Your users have to manually purchase a new one at the new price, and someone (you or them) has to take responsibility for cancelling their old subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the subscription price. However, you can't charge the new price without user's agreement. Once you changed the price, the existing subscribers will have to manually accept the new price. Otherwise, it will be cancelled.
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#change-price-sub

Google Play has provided a ConfirmPriceChange API in their Play Billing Library:
https://joebirch.co/2019/03/12/handling-pricing-changes-with-the-google-play-billing-library/

AFAIK, there is no way to meet your "one-year old price" requirement.